# Pandas what is the row of error and enter substitution value on dtype error

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in a large tab separated file with Pandas. I am trying to declare the dtypes prior to reading the data. I am getting errors with some data records. The file is so large that I don't know what row the error data is and what value (or maybe null) is causing the error. The column that is causing the error is "Cert#" which is supposed to be a positive int.

some code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_cols = [ "Date", "code", "many other cols", "Cert#", "Column 19"] 
my_types = { "code": str, "result#": np.float64, "Cert#": np.int64}

df = pd.read_table(file_path, usecols=my_cols, parse_dates=["Date"], dtype=my_types, sep='\t',  engine='python', encoding="ISO-8859-1", on_bad_lines = 'warn')
```

The error:

> ValueError: Unable to convert column Cert# to type int64

- So is it possible to have pandas print the error row so I can see the bad Cert# value? I tried `on_bad_lines = 'warn'`.
- Is it possible to substitute the value that causes the error with -999 ? Which the -999 does not occur in the data because all Cert# are positive integers.

Comment: What happens if you don't specify the dtypes when reading the data? Pandas might solve the problem on its own

Comment: @Viktor, What if the problem is there is a line with less columns? So there ends up being less separators.

Comment: @Viktor The "Cert#" ends up being the 9th column and when I remove it from my_types. I then get an errors and the 13th column then 14th, then the 15th...

Comment: What happens if you try `pd.read_table(file_path, usecols=my_col)` without the rest? And what kind of file are you trying to read?

Answer (score 0):

So the question/comments from Viktor were helpful with solving the problem.

This is what I did.

```
df = pd.read_table(file_path, usecols=my_col, sep='\t', engine='python', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df["Cert#"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Cert#"], errors = "coerce")
df = df[df["Cert#"].isna()]
print(df)
```

This showed the rows that were causing the errors. There was a row with text strings in all columns.